# Pytorch save Checkpoint RuntimeError: unsupported Storage type

Tags: pytorch, checkpoint

When trying to save a model's state_dict and other parameters I get a runtime error of Unsupported type.

Background:
I have an imagenet model loaded to my CUDA device and everything trains well. However, trying to torch.save the model.state_dict() the error above results. If I create another simple model, keep it on the CPU and use torch.save on it, no errors result. However, if I load that same model onto my GPU results in the same error. So it seems I can't save from GPU. But it seems I should be able to do that. Does anyone have a solution?

**Error:**

```
  0%|          | 0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
  0%|          | 0/446 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
/home/gyasis/miniconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:718: UserWarning: Named tensors and all their associated APIs are an experimental feature and subject to change. Please do not use them for anything important until they are released as stable. (Triggered internally at  /pytorch/c10/core/TensorImpl.h:1156.)
  return torch.max_pool2d(input, kernel_size, stride, padding, dilation, ceil_mode)
div by zero
[1,    21] loss: 2.822
[1,    41] loss: 2.255
[1,    61] loss: 1.975
[1,    81] loss: 1.813
[1,   101] loss: 1.697
[1,   121] loss: 1.609
[1,   141] loss: 1.542
[1,   161] loss: 1.482
[1,   181] loss: 1.439
[1,   201] loss: 1.403
[1,   221] loss: 1.366
[1,   241] loss: 1.338
[1,   261] loss: 1.315
[1,   281] loss: 1.294
[1,   301] loss: 1.273
[1,   321] loss: 1.257
[1,   341] loss: 1.241
[1,   361] loss: 1.227
[1,   381] loss: 1.212
[1,   401] loss: 1.197
[1,   421] loss: 1.187
[1,   441] loss: 1.176
Epoch: 0, Loss: 1.17, Accuracy: 0.58
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/media/gyasis/Blade 15 SSD/Users/gyasi/Google Drive (not syncing)/Collection/playground/chest/deep_model.py in <cell line: 5>()
      329 #save trained model with hyperparameters
----> 333 training(model, train_dataloader, num_epochs)
      334 experiment.end()

/media/gyasis/Blade 15 SSD/Users/gyasi/Google Drive (not syncing)/Collection/playground/chest/deep_model.py in training(model, train_dataloader, num_epochs)
     320 print(f'Epoch: {epoch}, Loss: {avg_loss:.2f}, Accuracy: {acc:.2f}')
     321 experiment.log_metric("Accuracy", acc, epoch)
---> 322 save_model(model, optimizer, scheduler, 'chest_model', num_epochs, avg_loss, acc)

/media/gyasis/Blade 15 SSD/Users/gyasi/Google Drive (not syncing)/Collection/playground/chest/deep_model.py in save_model(model, optimizer, scheduler, model_name, num_epochs, loss, best_loss, save_dir)
     265 loss_path = os.path.join(model_dir, 'loss.pt')
     266 best_loss_path = os.path.join(model_dir, 'best_loss.pt')
---> 267 torch.save(model.state_dict(), model_path)
     268 torch.save(optimizer.state_dict(), optimizer_path)
     269 torch.save(scheduler.state_dict(), scheduler_path)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/serialization.py:379, in save(obj, f, pickle_module, pickle_protocol, _use_new_zipfile_serialization)
    377 if _use_new_zipfile_serialization:
    378     with _open_zipfile_writer(opened_file) as opened_zipfile:
--> 379         _save(obj, opened_zipfile, pickle_module, pickle_protocol)
    380         return
    381 _legacy_save(obj, opened_file, pickle_module, pickle_protocol)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/serialization.py:484, in _save(obj, zip_file, pickle_module, pickle_protocol)
    482 pickler = pickle_module.Pickler(data_buf, protocol=pickle_protocol)
    483 pickler.persistent_id = persistent_id
--> 484 pickler.dump(obj)
    485 data_value = data_buf.getvalue()
    486 zip_file.write_record('data.pkl', data_value, len(data_value))

File ~/miniconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py:99, in Tensor.__reduce_ex__(self, proto)
     97 def __reduce_ex__(self, proto):
     98     if type(self) is Tensor:
---> 99         return self._reduce_ex_internal(proto)
    100     relevant_args = (self,)
    101     from torch.overrides import has_torch_function, handle_torch_function

File ~/miniconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py:172, in Tensor._reduce_ex_internal(self, proto)
    170     return (torch._utils._rebuild_sparse_tensor, args_sparse)
    171 else:
--> 172     args = (self.storage(),
    173             self.storage_offset(),
    174             tuple(self.size()),
    175             self.stride(),
    176             self.requires_grad,
    177             backward_hooks)  # previously was self._backward_hooks
    178     return (torch._utils._rebuild_tensor_v2, args)

RuntimeError: unsupported Storage type
time: 1h 31min 54s
```

**Simple Model test in the same runtime:**

```
EPOCH = 5
PATH = "model.pt"
LOSS = 0.4

torch.save({
            'epoch': EPOCH,
            'model_state_dict': net.state_dict(),
            'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict(),
            'loss': LOSS,
            }, PATH)

print(type(net.state_dict()))

<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>
time: 608 µs

#model to cuda
net = net.to(device)

EPOCH = 5
PATH = "model.pt"
LOSS = 0.4

torch.save({
            'epoch': EPOCH,
            'model_state_dict': net.state_dict(),
            'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict(),
            'loss': LOSS,
            }, PATH)
```

Output

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [77], in <cell line: 5>()
      2 PATH = "model.pt"
      3 LOSS = 0.4
----> 5 torch.save({
      6             'epoch': EPOCH,
      7             'model_state_dict': net.state_dict(),
      8             'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict(),
      9             'loss': LOSS,
     10             }, PATH)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/serialization.py:379, in save(obj, f, pickle_module, pickle_protocol, _use_new_zipfile_serialization)
    377 if _use_new_zipfile_serialization:
    378     with _open_zipfile_writer(opened_file) as opened_zipfile:
--> 379         _save(obj, opened_zipfile, pickle_module, pickle_protocol)
    380         return
    381 _legacy_save(obj, opened_file, pickle_module, pickle_protocol)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/serialization.py:484, in _save(obj, zip_file, pickle_module, pickle_protocol)
    482 pickler = pickle_module.Pickler(data_buf, protocol=pickle_protocol)
    483 pickler.persistent_id = persistent_id
--> 484 pickler.dump(obj)
    485 data_value = data_buf.getvalue()
    486 zip_file.write_record('data.pkl', data_value, len(data_value))

File ~/miniconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py:99, in Tensor.__reduce_ex__(self, proto)
     97 def __reduce_ex__(self, proto):
     98     if type(self) is Tensor:
---> 99         return self._reduce_ex_internal(proto)
    100     relevant_args = (self,)
    101     from torch.overrides import has_torch_function, handle_torch_function

File ~/miniconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py:172, in Tensor._reduce_ex_internal(self, proto)
    170     return (torch._utils._rebuild_sparse_tensor, args_sparse)
    171 else:
--> 172     args = (self.storage(),
    173             self.storage_offset(),
    174             tuple(self.size()),
    175             self.stride(),
    176             self.requires_grad,
    177             backward_hooks)  # previously was self._backward_hooks
    178     return (torch._utils._rebuild_tensor_v2, args)

RuntimeError: unsupported Storage type
time: 33.9 ms
```

**Environment:**

Python 3.8.12

Torch 1.9.0+cu102